# My React Component breaks when I use this.state

Tags: reactjs, components, render, renderer

I'm trying to write a simple React component that counts the amount of characters entered into a text field. The component is rendered fine, but when I try and reference this.state, the component breaks and the screen is blank.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #content {
   width: 800px; 
   margin-left: auto; 
   margin-right: auto; 
 }

 body {
   background-color: #F1FAEE; ;
 }

 h1 {
   font-family: Avenir; 
   color: black; 
   font-size: 44px; 
 }
```

JavaScript:

```
class Box extends React.Component {

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      text: this.props.text
    }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      text: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div> 
        <h1>This App Counts Letters</h1>
        <textarea value = {this.props.text} onChange = {this.handleChange}>  </textarea> 
        <h1>{this.state.text.length}</h1> 
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Box text = "I find this  frustrating"/>,document.getElementById("content"))
```

The issue is with {this.state.text.length} 
Things render if that line is changed to {this.props.text.length}

Comment: Did you try to debug? apparently `this.state.text` is either undefined or it does not have `length` property. Also, it is unclear what "breaks" means. Usually, if you open the browser console, you can see the error so you can avoid posting this sort of questions.

Answer (score 2):

React ES6 classes don´t have a `getInitialState()` function, you need to use the `constructor` function to set your initial state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: props.text};
}
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes

Or you switch back to `React.createClass()`

Comment: Thank you for this insight! I was getting pretty frustrated with this script.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of notes to make so I'm just going to re-write and comment as I go.

I haven't tested it, but this should work.

```
class Box extends React.Component {

  // getInitialState() {} should be replaced in ES6 with:
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: props.text
    }
  }

  // This looks good.
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      text: event.target.value
    })
  }
```

The value of a textarea element is BETWEEN `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`. Not stored as a 'value' attribute as you had it originally.

Next, that value should be STATE not PROPS since it needs to update.

Finally, you probably are having problems because in handleChange, `this` is not bound correctly. I replaced it with '() => this.handleChange()' because the fat arrow in ES6 (=>) will fix that for you.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div> 
        <h1>This App Counts Letters</h1>
        <textarea onChange = {() => this.handleChange()}>{this.state.text}</textarea> 
        <h1>{this.state.text.length}</h1> 
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Box text = "I find this  frustrating"/>,document.getElementById("content"))
```

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you for being generous.

Comment: The arrow function didn't seem to solve the problem. I did find another solution provided by someone, though, and that solution was to use this.handleChange = this.handlChange.bind(this) in the constructor function. It took me a while to understand what the bind method was accomplishing, but now it seems clear...atm haha